# belongs_to proc is not getting executed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, model-associations

I have this code in one of my model.

```
  class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :user, -> { includes :user_profile }

  end
```

and when i try to load associated user of a comment user_profile is not loaded.

```
   comment.user.association(:user_profile).loaded?
   => false
```

please help.

Comment: Is it really not getting executed? What if you put a `puts` in the lambda?

Comment: yes i tried putting `byebug` and `puts` statement in that block.

Comment: @AndreyDeineko as per `belongs_to :user, -> { includes :user_profile }` this code user_profile should load as soon as i load user of a comment, right?

Comment: Super strange. Tested in rails 5 and rails 4.2 and it's working for me. When you test the relation on the user directly, does it work?

Comment: @radubogdan my rails version is `4.0.13`.

Comment: [Go here](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.1/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/belongs_to) and search for "Scopes" further down the page. If you change the api to less than 4.2 that section does not exist.

Comment: I don't have any rails project running on 4.1 or 4.0 to test this locally, but I'm not sure that is supported.

Comment: Based on [rails-4 source code examples](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-0-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations.rb#L1184) looks like this is working with `has_many` and `has_and_belongs_to_many`.